# Python - ImportError: No module named 'vector'

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\marcos_brinner\Desktop\jogo.py", line 11, in <module>
from vector import *
ImportError: No module named 'vector'
```

I can't find the `vector` module online.

[Code](http://pastebin.com/VW9maqHf) is as follows:

```
try:
    import sys
    import random
    import math
    import os
    import getopt
    import pygame
    import pickle
    import copy
    from collections import *
    from socket import *
    from pygame.locals import *
    from vector import *
    import yaml
    import pygame.mixer
    import ConfigParser

except ImportError, err:
    print "couldn't load module. %s" % (err)
    sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: Can you add the link to the tutorial not just the full code?

Comment: isn't the tutorial link it's a full code link was my  fault to write the "tutorial link"

Comment: Is there a context where you obtained this code from?

Comment: i found it here [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUCyfdzP-i8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the description given below the video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUCyfdzP-i8). It is clearly written "I've also used this module for 2d vectors: (change "vec2d" to "vector")
http://www.pygame.org/wiki/2DVectorClass" .so copy the code from link and save it into the same folder as jogo.py i.e in your case "C:\Users\marcos_brinner\Desktop\vector.py".
PS: do not forget to rename your class vec2d to class vector.

Comment: Oh man you saved my life, thank you so  much was my fault to not read this. and was exaclity it solved.